# Tuple and summaring

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming

How to write a function that will check if you can summ up all tuple elements or not

```
template <size_t ID, class T>
int check(const T& p)
{
    size_t n = std::tuple_size_v<T>;
    auto sum = std::get<0>(p);
    if constexpr (ID < std::tuple_size_v<T>) {
        if (sum += std::get<ID>(p)) {
            check<ID + 1>(p);
        }
        else
...
```

Comment: Do you want all types to be arithmetic types? The same arithmetic types? Do you want to simply be able to call + on all neighbouring pairs as in a fold expression?

Comment: Expanding on @alterigel's questions, do you want to consider promotions?  Do you want to force the sum to be of the same type as the first element?  That is what your code snippet is suggesting?

Comment: Would you want a tuple of strings to pass your check? Strings support `operator+` but the operation is rarely referred to as "summation". What should be the focus of your check: use of the symbol `+` or use of an operation that produces something commonly called "sum"? (I guess I'm stuck trying to define "can summ up".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use partial specialization and fold expressions to check if for a `std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>`, it's possible to call `T1{} + T2{} + T3{}`;

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename Tuple, typename = void>
struct check_impl : public std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct check_impl<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::void_t<decltype((std::declval<Ts>() + ...))>> : public std::true_type {};

template <typename Tuple>
constexpr bool check = check_impl<Tuple>::value;

int main() {
    std::cout << check<std::tuple<int, double, char>> << " " << check<std::tuple<int, std::string>>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative way to achieve the same and more efficient result:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto check_impl(...) noexcept -> bool { return false; }

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto check_impl(int) noexcept -> decltype((std::declval<Ts>() + ...), bool{}) {
    return true;
}

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr bool check(std::tuple<Ts...>) noexcept {
    return check_impl<Ts...>(0);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << check(std::tuple<int, double, char>{}) << ' ' << check(std::tuple<int, std::string>{});
}
```